# AWS Cognito with Java Hibernate and Jersey backend

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hibernate, dropwizard

I am using `java` [Dropwizard](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard) framework to handle REST APIs as backend server. It uses Hibernate and Jersay to communicate with data. 
 
 I want to add **[AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)** for authentication, although all of Signup/Signin flow will be handled by frontend side, I want to authenticate all my APIs with JWT token with a `middleware`. so that all of the APIs will be secured. 

I am unable to find any solution to tackle this problem. Is there any `maven` library to handle this.
Any suggestion/lead will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Dropwizard appears to support [OAuth2](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/auth.html#oauth2), combined with standard things like `@RolesAllowed`.  That would be a way forward.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit. I am new in AWS Cognito. any reference.

Comment: did you solve it? can you show how?